# Navigation to URL

Tags: navigation

My navigation looks like so:

```
<li><a href="{{ url('http://www.mysite.com/') }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == 'home' %}class="active"{% endif %}>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ siteUrl('services') }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == 'service' %}class="active"{% endif %}>Services</a></li>
```

But when I click on "services", I get 404 not found.  What I'm trying to understand is where is my URL? I thought it would be something like `www.mysite.com/index.php/services`.

I have tried laying this out in both public HTML part of my server and the Craft folder.

My folder structure is:

```
Route/
    css/
    img/
    index.php
    _layout.html
    _services.html; this is the file i need to navigate to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. 
You don't need to put "('service')" inside your twig code plus you don't need to enter your siteUrl.

If you fill the href with `/services` it should work like supposed to.

If you are having trouble with `index.php` being in your URL you should check this guide out in the docs.

https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php

Another thing,
You shouldn't put any HTML / Template files inside your public_html folder. They should all be in the `craft/templates` folder.

More in the docs here: https://craftcms.com/docs/folder-structure

Also make sure you made a entry for the page you want in this case "services".

If you keep finding problems like this you should try the Craft CMS Slack channel. Over 4000 developers joined already and are able to help you in a more direct way.

https://craftcms.com/community#slack